# Como calcular +10.5% em um produto

Tags: c#, webforms, decimal, value

Como calcular +10.5% em um produto?

O meu cálculo está assim:

```
private void txtMargemLucro_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtPrecoVenda.Text = (Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrecoCusto.Text) * 
                          Convert.ToDecimal(txtMargemLucro.Text) / 100 +    
                          Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrecoCusto.Text)).ToString();
}
```

Esse método coloca mascara no `txtPrecoVenda` que recebe resultado e esta formatado

```
public void Moeda(ref TextBox txt)
{
    string n = string.Empty;
    decimal v = 0;
    try
    {
        n = txt.Text.Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "");
        if (n.Equals(""))
            n = "";
        n = n.PadLeft(3, '0');
        if (n.Length > 3 & n.Substring(0, 1) == "0")
            n = n.Substring(1, n.Length - 1);
        v = Convert.ToDecimal(n) / 100;
        txt.Text = string.Format("{0:N}", v);
        txt.SelectionStart = txt.Text.Length;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

o valor retorna correto se for valor inteiro `15%`, mas se for 10.5% dá erro.

Comment: Na prática, o que significa "dá erro"? Seria bom [edit] a pergunta e explicar melhor qual foi o resultado obtido, e o que você esperava como correto.

Comment: Se você dividir por 1000 e multiplicar por 105, seria equivalente.

Comment: Qual é a finalidade de `if (n.Equals("")) n = "";`?